# Canonical way to define forward output iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator-traits

How does one define forward-output-iterators in C++11 in a canonical way?

According to the standard a forward_iterator is only a input_iterator. So the corresponding `forward_iterator_tag` only extends `input_iterator_tag`. If we are using `std::iterator` to define our iterators, what tag do we use for a forward-output-iterator?

Is it canonical to define a private tag that extends both `forward_iterator_tag` and `output_iterator_tag` or is there a better solution?

Comment: inheriting from both of them will do

Comment: As a side question: does anybody know if these mutable iterator tags were considered for the standard library? And if so, why were they not included?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The canonical thing to do is to inherit from `std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>` only. Iterators have only one category.

The standard has no algorithms (or other uses) for an output iterator that is also a forward iterator. All uses of output iterators in the standard require only single-pass.

Instead, the standard has the idea of mutable vs. immutable iterators of categories forward/bidi/randomaccess. All the algorithms that need to write through iterators, and that require better than single-pass, also read through the same iterators they write through. This is `std::remove`, `std::sort` and other mutating algorithms.

The difference between mutable and immutable iterators is not detected by iterator tag, it's determined by whether the assignment expressions are well-formed. So for example if you pass an iterator to `std::sort` that's immutable, then the algorithm won't compile anyway, so there's generally no need for an input iterator to also be tagged with `output_iterator_tag`. All algorithms that require an `OutputIterator` will Just Work with a mutable `ForwardIterator`, again there is no need for it to be tagged with `output_iterator_tag`.

If you have different needs from those of the standard algorithms then I can't immediately think of a reason that your proposal won't work for your iterators. But it won't detect mutable standard iterators. For example `std::deque<int>::iterator` and `int*` have iterator category `random_access_iterator_tag`, not your private tag and not anything to do with `output_iterator_tag`. So you would probably be better off defining your own traits class rather than hoping to adapt the existing `iterator_traits::iterator_category` to provide the information you want.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared things up quite much. In the end this implies that immutable iterators return const references/copies of the pointed to element to prevent assignment via the returned reference, right?

Comment: @MFH: that's right. Immutable iterators over containers return `const T&` (I haven't checked whether that's actually required, or if they're allowed to return proxies instead). Other immutable iterators can return anything convertible to `T`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: this is probably overdue for an updated, since use of `std::iterator` has been deprecated for a while now.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: go for it :-) . I'm not tracking C++ any more so I'd have to look up the new correct answer.