# STL fill and forward iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

According to most C++ references, for instance cplusplus.com, [forward iterators](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ForwardIterator/) are not required to be assignable (I mean, deferenced to an lvalue). However, for several STL algorithms that need to write values, for instance [`std::fill`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/?kw=fill) (also `std::generate` etc.), the specification uses forward iterator:

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
  void fill (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& val);
```

while the equivalent behavior requires lvalue dereference:

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
  void fill (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& val)
{
  while (first != last) {
    *first = val;
    ++first;
  }
}
```

So, it is actually using a mutable forward iterator with a single pass.

Now the questions are:

(1) Why not make it clear that the forward iterators used in these cases are mutable?

(2) **Update**: I found the following question to be stupid: I temporarily forgot that output iterators do not need to support equality comparison. The above question remains, anyway.

Why use forward iterators instead of output iterators for `std::fill`, `std::generate` etc. while they do not actually need multiple passes? (`std::copy` only needs output iterators, for instance. What's the rationale?)

Comment: `forward iterators are not required to be assignable`, how did you determine that? I'm pretty sure they are assignable.

Comment: @JesseGood For practical purposes they are almost always assignable, but if you read the reference http://cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ForwardIterator/?kw=forward%20iterator it isn't.

Comment: @JesseGood I also found this on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058642/are-forward-iterators-output-iterators

Comment: Thanks for the link, I was unaware of that. That link also is linked to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062297/canonical-way-to-define-forward-output-iterator) which I think answers your question.

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks, an interesting read. After reading the thread you referred to, the problem seems more like a defect in the standard to me.

Answer (score 5):

From the signature

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
void fill (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& val);
```

you cannot infer that `ForwardIterator` is an iterator described in [forward iterator](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ForwardIterator/). However, if you read the parameter description, you will find that `first` and `last` must be

> [Forward Iterators](http://cplusplus.com/ForwardIterator) to the initial and final positions in a sequence of elements **that support being assigned a value of type T**.

(emphasis by me). So a forward iterator that fulfills nothing more than what is required of a forward iterator is not a valid argument.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. But the signature is tricky from a standard point of view.

Comment: The alternative would be to introduce a new name for forward iterators that support assignemt to the pointed to element.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem terribly strange to me, given that the specification for `fill` is that the (dereferenced) iterator be assignable from `T`. An output iterator won't suffice because it's not comparable to determine the range end, so a `forward_iterator` with requirements was chosen.

You'll note that `fill_n` *does* use output iterators because no iterator comparison is needed to determine the end of the sequence to fill.

Comment: I think OP’s point is that the forward iterator concept is *required* but not *sufficient* to specify the requirements for the argument type. The same would go for “output iterator”; only by requiring that the argument be *both* do we get the correct semantics. Put differently, there are forward iterators on which `std::fill` cannot be called.